# Mathematical journals which accept micro-articles

Tags: mathematics, journals, publishers, publishability

A **micro-article** is a paper of at most six pages.

The following mathematical journals accept micro-articles:

- *Elemente der Mathematik*,
- *Examples and Counterexamples* and
- *Journal of Computational Mathematics and Data Science*.

Any other example?

Comment: This is a shopping question. You may want to take the tour: https://academia.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Proceedings of the AMS, Bulletin of the LMS, Archiv der Mathematik, Comptes Rendus. Mathématique (all these journals specalize exclusively in short papers).

Comment: @theL Thank you!

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise. Any math journal will accept a short paper if it contains results that meet the journal’s standards for quality and significance. In other words, journals do not have a lower bound on article length. The only exception I’m aware of is Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society, which is technically a journal but publishes book-length articles as monographs. I think they won’t consider an article of less than 80 pages.